# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. typescript 'strict'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to replace an object using SDK, and typescript throws the following error with the 'strict' mode on,

```
const offer = client.offer(oldOfferDefinition!.id);
await offer.replace(newOfferDefinition);
```

**error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.**

```
const offer = client.offer(oldOfferDefinition!.id);
```

I am sure that oldOfferDefinition has id and it has a value, how can i get rid of this compliation error?

Comment: I guess it's happen because `client.offer` have `(id: string): Promise<...>` signature and method expect string as first param (strictly), but using [Non-null assertion (!.)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) you _are not_ guarantee that `oldOfferDefinition` is not nullish.

Comment: "*I am sure that oldOfferDefinition has id and it has a value*" - but did you express this in the types? Please show us the type definitions you use and the declaration of `oldOfferDefinition`, otherwise we won't be able to help you with the problem.

Comment: You might be looking for `client.offer(oldOfferDefinition!.id!);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that it does, then throw an exception if it doesn't.

```
const id = oldOfferDefinition!.id;
if (typeof id === "undefined") {
    throw new Error("ID for old offer is undefined");
}
const offer = client.offer(id);
```

Since the runtime can't reach the line where you pass the value to `offer` if that value is undefined, then the TS compiler will be happy with it.

Comment: Thank you, one more question. console.log("Database with id of " + Def && Def.id + "' was found"); Object is possibly 'undefined' in Def.id , can I do Def?.id?

Comment: `Def?.id` just means that if `Def` is `undefined` then the whole expression will be `undefined` (instead of trying to read `id` from `undefined`, failing and throwing an exception). Since the problem is that you aren't allowed to pass `undefined` in the next line: No!

Answer (score 0):

remove ! mark form oldOfferDefinition, and encapsulte this to condition

```js
if(oldOfferDefinition){
    const offer: string = client.offer(oldOfferDefinition.id);
    await offer.replace(newOfferDefinition);
}
```

but you should secure, that the result type of offer() function is defined as string